# How do I make each ListView element create a unique activity [Android Studio - Kotlin]

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, onclick

I'm new to Android Development and Kotlin, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

So I've created an app in which there's a ListView which, once clicked, takes you to a new activity. However, for every element in the ListView, it takes me to the same activity. How do I change it so that every element takes me to a unique activity?

Here's my code so far (not all of it, the important bits, but please let me know if you'd like to see more)

**MainActivity.kt**

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.main_ListView)
        listView.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this) // custom adapter --> tells list what to render

        listView.isClickable = true
        listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, _, _ ->
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_uni_detail)
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context): BaseAdapter() {

        private val mContext: Context = context

        private val nameOfUni = arrayListOf<String>(
                "University of Toronto", "University of Waterloo", "McMaster University"
        )

        // responsible for rows
        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return nameOfUni.size
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return "TEST STRING"
        }

        // responsible for rendering out each row
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?): View {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            val rowMain = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_main, viewGroup, false)

            val uniNameTextView = rowMain.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.uniName)
            uniNameTextView.text = nameOfUni.get(position)

            return rowMain

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good implementation .First of all you should implement onClickListener in your adapter. for example on `uniNameTextView` not on the hole list. For the details activity you should not create a unique activity for every item , you must create **one** activity and for every item that is clicked ,you send the details to the activity.

```
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.main_ListView)
            listView.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this) // custom adapter --> tells list what to render

        }
    
        private class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context,onClick:OnClick): BaseAdapter() {
    
            private val mContext: Context = context
    
            private val nameOfUni = arrayListOf<String>(
                    "University of Toronto", "University of Waterloo", "McMaster University"
            )
    
            // responsible for rows
            override fun getCount(): Int {
                return nameOfUni.size
            }
    
            override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
                return position.toLong()
            }
    
            override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
                return "TEST STRING"
            }
    
            // responsible for rendering out each row
            override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?): View {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                val rowMain = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_main, viewGroup, false)
    
                val uniNameTextView = rowMain.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.uniName)
                uniNameTextView.text = nameOfUni.get(position)
                uniNameTextView.setOnClickListener{
                   ////////////////////////// here 
                   val intent = Intent(this, DetailsActivity::class.java)
                   intent.putExtra("samplename", nameOfUni.get(position))
                   startActivity(intent)   
                }
                return rowMain
    
            }
    
        }
```

**DetailActivity:**

```
class DetailActivity :AppCompact() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_details)
            val ss:String = intent.getStringExtra("samplename")
           text_view_detail.text=ss
   }
}
```